# Django form with ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I'm building a simple application using Django where I can record and track information of a set of quality control tests performed regularly to radiotherapy and radiology equipment. It shows a list of all equipment available which I can then select to either perform a set of tests or review other activities performed previously. For now everything seems to be working. I can create new equipments, new tests and filter the tests related to that equipment. But now I'm facing a problem that I can't solve. Here is a sample of my code with the models that I'm struggling:

```
/models.py
class Test(models.Model):
    testgroup = models.ForeignKey(TestGroup)
    equipament = models.ManyToManyField(Equipament, blank=True)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    frequency = models.ForeignKey(Frequency, null=True, blank=True)
    tolerance = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s%s%s %s' % (self.testgroup.modality, self.testgroup.abbreviation, self.number, self.name)

    pass


class Activity(models.Model):
    CONFORMANCE_CHOICES = (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),   
    )
    equipament = models.ForeignKey(Equipament, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    test = models.ManyToManyField(Teste, blank=True)
    conformance = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CONFORMANCE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.date, self.equipament)

        pass
```

What I need to do is to be able to save a result, one of the conformance choices to each test. I am able to display in the Activity view a list of the tests I want to perform but how can I save that conformance field for each test? My best approach was to change the conformance field to a ManyToManyField and through the form create the relations between Tests and Conformance but I get for each test all the conformance choices. How can I define just one conformance choice (the selected one) to one test? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this out. I am posting my solution. Maybe someone had or will have the same problem. To perform what I wanted I used `inlinefomset_factory` creating an intermediary model called `Results` with a `ForeignKey` to `Activity`. Everything works now.